# C# 2010 Express - Missing Pointer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Where has my pointer gone :'(

In the designer at the top of each category in the toolbox, I have "border" not "pointer" anymore.  I don't know how I have managed this or how to set it back.  I can obviously work around this by just finding the control I want to edit in the xaml but its frustrating to say the least.  Does anybody know how to set it back, or what I did to screw it up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a version setting problem.

To fix it right click over the toolbox and select Reset Toolbox.

A Microsoft connect issue was posted last year with the issue, but the user couldnt reproduce the problem, if you can reproduce it maybe send it in and they can fix the problem:

http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/510755/2010-pointer-missing-from-toolbox

Comment: Ha! that old cookie.  I followed your advice and the toolbox is back as before.  Can't reproduce the problem for the guys at Microsoft though :(.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The WPF toolbox is not without problems.  I've always managed to whack it back into shape by right-clicking it and choosing Reset.